# htaccess rewrite to hash for ajax

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, fragment-identifier

Basically I'd like to emulate what Hypem.com does with their urls, if you go to [hypem.com/popular](http://hypem.com/popular) you get redirected to [hypem.com/#/popular](http://hypem.com/#/popular)

How can I do this with htaccess? I have several basic urls that I need to redirect, all others stay the same, for example, these two need to redirect:

- `/news`
- `/contact`

But `/admin` shouldn't

Comment: Facebook does the same. Is it the only possibility to edit the URL in the Browser line?

Answer (score 3):

This code worked for me:

```
## REWRITE RULES
# enable rewrite
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(news|contact)(/?)(.*)$ #/$1$2$3 [R,NC,NE,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like they do it with javascript:

```
url = document.location.pathname + document.location.search;
url = url.replace(/\?ax=1/,'');
url = "/#" + url;
top.location = url;
```

That is from the source of http://hypem.com/popular

Comment: Won't changing the location with javascript make a new request to the page? If you visit hypem.com/popular you get redirected but pressing back won't take you to hypem.com/popular, it will take you back to whatever site you were on before